# Type Mismatch with Application.Match, only on MAC

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro created and works well on windows, however, when  I ran the on a MAC, there is a type mismatch error. What is wrong with below code? it happened at line `If IsError(Application.Match(myValue, value_range, 0)) Then`:

```
Sub HideAndSeek()


Rows("3:5676").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

myValue = InputBox("Type in an ID")

If myValue = "" Then Exit Sub

value_range = Columns("A:A")


If IsError(Application.Match(myValue, value_range, 0)) Then

   MsgBox "No ID found"
   Exit Sub

Else

    index_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myValue, value_range, 0)


End If


Rows(index_num).RowHeight = 120

End Sub
```

Comment: it happened at line "If IsError(Application.Match(myValue, value_range, 0)) Then"

Comment: Does `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` work? `Application.Match` is working off the extended COM interface of `Application`, which may or may not be MAC-friendly (no idea, just a stab in the dark) - note that `WorksheetFunction.Xxxx` will raise a run-time error that you'll have to handle, instead of returning an error value like `Application.Xxxx` does. Just why are you making the call *twice*?

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction.Match doesn't work either. I am always using a windows, so I have not issue of running this code. My coworker uses APPLE, and I am not familiar with MAC, and what is the different. I made the call twice, because I want to check whether the ID exists or not, if it does't give an error message, if it does, return the row contains the ID.

Comment: Yet you could store the return value in a `Variant`, verify if `IsError` returns `True` or `False`, and then assign `index_num` to that returned value: no need to make the same function call twice.